# Should I refrain from trimming pubic and facial hair if I want to offer a sacrifrice?

Tags: hair, udhiyyah

I know you shouldn't cut your nails and hair for Qurbani (sacrifice) but is that including facial and pubic hair?
If we can't cut facial and pubic hair, can we just trim it?

Comment: Whether a man should cut or shave his beard might be discussed, but on the level that it is either makrooh or haram or not rceommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended or obligatory to not cut the hair and nails after the month of Dhul-Hijjah has begun, based on hadith:

> #### إذا دخلت العشر وأراد أحدكم أن يضحى فلايمس من شعره وبشره شيئا
>
> When the ten days (of Dhul-Hijjah) begin and one of you wants to offer a sacrifice, let him not touch anything of his hair or skin.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/35/53)</sup>

> #### من كان له ذبح يذبحه فإذا أهل هلال ذي الحجة فلا يأخذن من شعره ولا من أظفاره شيئا حتى يضحي
>
> Whoever has an animal to sacrifice, when the crescent moon of Dhul-Hijjah appears, let him not remove anything from his hair or nails, until he has offered his sacrifice.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/35/57)</sup>

It is mentioned without any restriction so the apparent meaning includes all hair of the body, including the hair of the pubic area, mustache, armpits etc. And it also includes cutting by trimming.

**Reference:**

- > والمراد بالنهي عن أخذ الظفر والشعر النهى عن إزالة الظفر بقلم أوكسر أو غيره والمنع من **إزالة الشعر بحلق أو تقصير أو نتف أو إحراق أو أخذه بنورة أو غير ذلك وسواء شعر الإبط والشارب والعانة والرأس وغير ذلك من شعور بدنه** قال إبراهيم المروزى وغيره من أصحابناحكم أجزاء البدن كلها حكم الشعر والظفر ودليله الرواية السابقة فلايمس من شعره وبشره شيئا
  >
  > <sup>— [Sharah Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/2948#p1)</sup>
- [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175381/if-a-person-wants-to-delay-the-udhiyah-until-the-days-of-at-tashreeq-11th-12th-and-13th-of-dhul-hijjah-is-it-haraam-for-him-to-remove-anything-of-his-hair-and-nails)